# Ошибки в примерах Gof паттернах Typescript

Tags: typescript, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучаю Gof паттерны

1. Вот пример Builder паттерна из https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/builder/typescript/example#lang-features
   Выдает ошибку

   builder.ts:17:11 - error TS2564: Property 'product' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

   17   private product: Product1;
   ~~~~~~~
   builder.ts:91:11 - error TS2564: Property 'builder' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

   91   private builder: Builder;

Кто знает как исправить?

2. также аналогичные ошибки в https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/prototype/typescript/example#lang-features

   error TS2564: Property 'component' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

   7   public component: object;
   ~~~~~
   prototype.ts:8:10 - error TS2564: Property 'circularReference' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

   8   public circularReference: ComponentWithBackReference;

Это обучающий сайт, а некоторые примеры кода не работают ( Может быть это связано с версиями TS?

Comment: Первая `private product?: Product1;` вторая точно также

Answer (score 0):

проблема решилась установкой в tsconfig.json параметра

```
 "strictPropertyInitialization": false
```